# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous' (Write via C# basic authentication)

Tags: c#, wcf

I get server error when I trying connect to webService. Do you know why?

**Error**

{System.Collections.Generic.SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection}

**Code**

```
            BasicHttpBinding basicbinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            basicbinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
            basicbinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
            basicbinding.Name = "HTTP_Port";

            WSPI.InvoiceCheck_OutClient invoiceCheck_OC = new WSPI.InvoiceCheck_OutClient(basicbinding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://example.example.eu:51200/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?senderParty=&amp;")));
            invoiceCheck_OC.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Login";
            invoiceCheck_OC.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";


            WSPI.InvoiceCheck invoiceCheck = new WSPI.InvoiceCheck();

            WSPI.InvoiceCheck_OutRequest invoiceCheck_OR = new WSPI.InvoiceCheck_OutRequest();

            WSPI.InvoiceConfirm invoiceCheck_IC = new WSPI.InvoiceConfirm();

            invoiceCheck.InvoiceNo = "1000000";
            invoiceCheck.IssueDate = "2014-01-01";
            invoiceCheck.VatNo = "88090302342";
            invoiceCheck.Username = "SuperRafal";


            string response = invoiceCheck_OC.InvoiceCheck_Out(invoiceCheck).Response.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code working correct there was a problem with link :) Sorry